# Qual o uso correto da tag "criptografia"?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Venho acompanhando a tag [criptografia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criptografia) - já que é um dos meus assuntos prediletos - e reparo que ela é comumente usada em situações que não tem nada a ver com [**cifragem**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptografia), mas com assuntos relacionados (hashing, assinatura digital, segurança da informação de um modo geral).

Em inglês é fácil, pois temos a palavra [**cryptography**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cryptography/info):

> Cryptography covers, among other things, encryption, hashing and digital signatures. Cryptography questions not directly related to software development are better asked at crypto.stackexchange.com.

E a palavra [**encryption**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/info):

> Encryption is the process of transforming information (called plaintext) using an algorithm (called cipher) to make it unreadable to anyone except those with special knowledge (often called a key). Conceptual questions about encryption may get better answers on crypto.stackexchange.com.

E suas respectivas tags. Bem como [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hash/info) (e as menos ambíguas [password-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/password-hash/info) e [hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hashcode/info)), [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/digital-signature/info) e [security](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/security/info).

Mas em português não temos palavras tão boas/sem ambiguidade (o verbo "criptografar" é mais ou menos direto, mas o substantivo "criptografia" não; e embora "decifrar" tenha um uso popular, "cifrar" não). Atualmente o wiki da tag usa esse significado mais restrito, mas boa parte das perguntas que a utilizam só estão contempladas pelo mais geral.

Como deve ser o uso dessa tag? Devemos manter o uso mais restrito - retageando as perguntas que não se aplicam - ou mudar para o uso mais geral - editando o wiki para refletir essa mudança?

Comment: Adicione alguns exemplos de perguntas que você acha que não se encaixam dentro do tema. Sabendo como essa tá está sendo mais "mal utilizada" é mais fácil propor uma solução para esses casos.

Comment: @Gabe Eu não acho que esteja mal utilizada, apenas queria saber a opinião da comunidade sobre usar o sentido mais geral ou o mais restrito. Me parece que há consenso em utilizar o sentido geral, então vamos por esse caminho!

Comment: @mgibsonbr Entendi. Eu não tenho preferência, principalmente por não ser muito a minha área, e eu não conseguir assimilar totalmente os prós/contras das alternativas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proponho que:

1. A tag Criptografia seja utilizada para perguntas diretamente relacionadas com conceitos de criptografia (incluíndo *hashing*)
2. A tag Encriptação seja utilizada em perguntas diretamente relacionadas com conceitos de encriptação (sempre reversíveis).
3. A tag Desencriptação seja utiliza em perguntas focadas no processo de reverter encriptação. Não me ocorre neste momento nenhum caso em que isto seja necessário.
4. A tag Cifragem seja marcada como sinónimo de Encriptação.
5. A tag Segurança seja utilizada para conceitos mais abrangentes e em cenários de aplicação mais prática, incluindo certificados.

Assim, classificaria as seguintes perguntas da seguinte forma:

- Como funciona o AES-256? Tanto criptografia como encriptação fazem sentido. Segurança faz sentido se o tema da pergunta incluir as implicações de segurança do AES-256, mas não pertence se for focada apenas nos conceitos/algoritmos abstratos.
- Devo encriptar os meus dados na base de dados? Criptografia, encriptação e segurança fazem todos sentido.
- Qual a diferença entre o SHA-256 e o bcrypt? Criptografia faz sentido, encriptação não. Segurança pode fazer sentido se o tema da pergunta incluir as aplicações práticas para segurança, mas não se for focada apenas nos conceitos/algoritmos abstratos.
- Como configurar o Apache para usar HTTPS? Criptografia e encriptação não fazem sentido, porque a pergunta é focada em conceitos de mais alto nível. Segurança faz sentido, e a tag "Certificado" pode fazer sentido se for uma parte importante da pergunta (por exemplo: como configurar o Apache para usar um certificado específico).
- Como implementar esteganografia? Creio que a pergunta seria fechada por ser demasiado vaga, mas a tag adequada seria segurança (e talvez a tag "esteganografia", se fizer sentido criar). Criptografia e encriptação só fazem sentido como tags se a pergunta for focada na comparação entre esteganografia e criptografia.

Answer (score 2):

Acho o uso mais amplo melhor. Ficaria como uma árvore B: a hora que houver muitas perguntas na tag mãe (criptografia), é só quebrá-la em filhas menores, mantendo a ligação à mãe (ex.: criptografia, assinatura-digital).

Acho que o SOPT segue esse mesmo princípio em geral: mais permissividade do que o SOEN quanto aos assuntos considerados on-topic (teoria de computação, por exemplo), com posterior criação de novos sites e realocação das perguntas quando ficar muito grande.